Why is my GitHub Actions workflow using pull_request_target being skipped in my pull request?
I want this workflow to run when <repo_root>/pom.xml is modified in the pull request using pull_request_target and not a regular pull_request configuration due to security requirements.
I have a PR open (ready for review and not a draft) with changes to the pom.xml, but the workflow keeps being skipped. I've tried several different configurations to the workflow, but it keeps being skipped. Can someone help me figure out why this is being skipped? I don't see any logging in GitHub Actions to figure out why this is happening. I'm out of ideas. Here's an excerpt of the workflow file:
name: Version Update Check

on:
  pull_request_target:
    paths:
      - 'pom.xml'

jobs:
  version_update_check:
    name: Version Update Check
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo at main
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: main
      - name: Determine current version
        run: |
          echo "CURRENT_POM_VERSION=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    ...
    ...


So pull_request_target actually isn't what you are looking for, you should be able to use regular pull_request. If you want to run your workflow only when there are changes to the pom.xml this is how you can do it:
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - pom.xml

pull_request_target is for the status of the pr I believe: docs
